# example of HD Wallet injection into RainbowKit

Tags: testing, wagmi, rainbowkit

I want to test my DApp which uses RainbowKit and WAGMI. I figured that the easiest way would be to use an [`HDWalletProvider`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider) and use it in the `createClient` function.

I was unable to find an example. Maybe that is because it is a daft idea. But I need to be able to test my DApp in headless mode and the `HDWalletProvider` seems to be the easiest solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Working on the same issue. This repo from wagmi lead dev is a starting point.
https://github.com/tmm/testing-wagmi

Still working on rainbowkit integration into tests.

@brightiron seems to have it all worked out in this repo:
https://github.com/OlympusDAO/olympus-frontend/blob/vite-demo/src/setupTests.tsx#L12-33